# Sigma-algebra generated by integer multiples

Tags: measure-theory

I came across this question and I'd like to check if my answer is correct. The problem is the following:

Consider the collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets $A_1,A_2,...$ of $\mathbb{Z}$
such that
$$A_i = \{ni \,|\,n \text{ is an integer}\}.$$
Determine the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$, denoted by $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

**My answer**: Since the sets $A_i$ are symmetric around $\{0\}$, I first noticed that, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, I can write
$$
\{-k,k\}=A_k\backslash\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_{i+k}\in\sigma(\mathcal{A}).
$$
Note also that, when $k=0$, $A_0$ is not defined, but we can write
$$
\{0\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\sigma(\mathcal{A}).
$$
Thus any complement, countable union or intersection of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ can be written as a union of sets of the form $\{-k,k\}$ and $\{0\}$, which are all in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$. Hence, $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ consists of all subsets $B$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that for each interger $k\in B$, we have $-k\in B$.

Is this enough?

Comment: You showed that all those sets are *in* $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$. You only have left to show that the sets you describe actually *form* a $\sigma$-algebra!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your argument precise consider $\{B \in \sigma (\mathcal A): -B=B\}$. ($-B$ stands for $\{-b: b\in B\}$). Verify that this is a sigma algebra and that it contains $\mathcal A$. Conclusion: $-B=B$ holds for every set $B$ in $\sigma (\mathcal A)$. Conversely, $-B=B$ implies $B=\cup_{k \in A} \{-k,k\} \cup \{0\}$ where $A=\{n \in B: n>0\}$. Thus, $B$ is a countable union of sets in $\sigma (\mathcal A)$ proving that $B \in \sigma (\mathcal A)$.

Comment: Thank you. What about the argument regarding the 'smallest $\sigma$-algebra', what can be said?