# $\sigma$-fields generated by multiples of natural numbers

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $k\mathbb{N} =\{k,2k,3k,\dots\}$.

What is the $\sigma$-field generated by the following collections

1. $\mathcal{B_1} = \{k\mathbb{N} : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$
2. $\mathcal{B_2} = \{k\mathbb{N} : k \ \ is \ a \ prime \}$

I can prove if the description of $\sigma$-field is given that it'll be generated by some given collection but I can't guess the other way. Any hints is appreciated.

Comment: For question 1, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084836/sigma-algebra-generated-by-integer-multiples?rq=1) is useful.

Comment: I have no clue why you decided to vandalise your post, but please don't do it in the future. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1. For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\{n\} = n\mathbb{N} \setminus \bigcup_{k \ge 2} kn\mathbb{N}$$
belong to the $\sigma$-field, so the
$\sigma(\mathcal{B}_1)$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$

Question 2. For every finite subset $F$ of the set of all prime numbers,
the set
$$A_F := \bigcap_{p \in F} p\mathbb{N} \cap \bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{P} \setminus F} (p\mathbb{N})^c.$$
belongs to $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_2)$. Those sets form a partition of $\mathbb{N}$, since each integer has finitely many prime divisors, and belong to $A_F$ if and only if $F$ is exactly the set of all prime divisors. This partition is countable. Hence $\sigma(\mathcal{B}_2)$ is the set of all arbitrary unions of sets of the form $A_F$.

Comment: Sorry, my definition of $A_F$ was incomplete, and I completed it. $A_F$ is the set of all positive integers whose set of prime divisors is exactly $F$.

Comment: Thank you, this finally answers the post :).  In 1h, I can award the bounty.